# CSS to Position Horizontal List

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a horizontal list using the style type below but when using display: inline the square wont show.  Any suggestions?

```
.vertical li {display: inline; list-style-type: square; padding-right: 5px;}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're titling your horizontal list as "vertical"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to style both the list and the list elements. Use float, not display:inline.

```
ul {list-style-type: square;}
li {float:left;margin-left:25px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

use float:left;
the you protect yourself from getting unexpected results that's inherited with diffrent objects